# UITableView design not worked right after Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I used UITableView in my app and used custom Cell with it, when view lunch its worked so good but when scroll table and set it again it like ugly, like images down.
[My normal tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyOKB.jpg)
[My tableView after Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dnf4.jpg)

```
DetailsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.sellPropertyLabel.text=sellPropertyArray[indexPath.row];
cell.sellPropertyTextField.delegate=self;

if (indexPath.row==0)
{

    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_realEstateTitle)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_realEstateTitle;
    }

}
else if (indexPath.row==1)
{

    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_desOfHomeInterior)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_desOfHomeInterior;
    }

}
else if (indexPath.row==2)
{
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_desOfGardenAndExter)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_desOfGardenAndExter;
    }

}
else if (indexPath.row==3)
{
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_locationOfTheProperty)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_locationOfTheProperty;
    }



}
else if (indexPath.row==4)
{

    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_whyBuyThisProperty)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_whyBuyThisProperty;
    }



}
else if (indexPath.row==5)
{
    //cell.selected=YES;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.enabled=NO;
    if (_country)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_country;
    }



}
else if (indexPath.row==6)
{
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.enabled=NO;
    if (_city)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_city;
    }


}
else if (indexPath.row==7)
{
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.enabled=NO;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_area)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_area;
    }


}
else if (indexPath.row==8)
{

    cell.sellPropertyTextField.enabled=NO;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_type)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_type;
    }

    //cell.addAlertTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;

}


else if (indexPath.row==9)
{
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.enabled=NO;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_pool)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_pool;
    }



}
else if (indexPath.row==10)
{
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.enabled=NO;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_status)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_status;
    }



}
else if (indexPath.row==11)
{


    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_bedrooms)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_bedrooms;
    }



}
else if (indexPath.row==12)
{


    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_bathrooms)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_bathrooms;
    }



}
else if (indexPath.row==13)
{


    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_livingSpaceSqm)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_livingSpaceSqm;
    }


}
else if (indexPath.row==14)
{


    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_landSqm)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_landSqm;
    }


}
else if (indexPath.row==15)
{


    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    if (_price)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_price;
    }



}
else if (indexPath.row==16)
{
    //cell.addAlertTextField.enabled=NO;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.sellPropertyTextField.enabled=NO;
    if (_currency)
    {
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.text=_currency;
    }


}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Any UITableView function?

Comment: do you use NSLayoutConstraint?

Comment: looks like you returning wrong cell height at -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I don't use this function, I used UITableView default height

Comment: cellatindexpath @Ahmed

Comment: [check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35606168/1880431)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the cells, because they are being reused.

Your code structure is a little difficult to modify, sometimes a switch case will be better. you can add this at the bottom before returning the cell:

```
switch(indexPath.row){
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 16:
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        break;
    default:
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        break;
}
return cell;
```

Comment: Its work for remove AccessoryDisclosureIndicator but still when scroll the textField background set to graycolor like country and city cell

Comment: I suggest 2 create 2 different  uitableview custom cell . Or make move the textfield below the label to make things consistent

Comment: Or expand on my example to adjust the other stuff

Comment: I modify your code and it worked right 
switch(indexPath.row){
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 16:
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.enabled=No;
        break;
    default:
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.sellPropertyTextField.enabled=YES;
        break;
}
return cell;

@meda   thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same `reuseIdentifier` for your cells. Please, share your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, but I am sure you have some string like `"ID"` there. You have 2 types of cells with different configurations so you should use different identifiers as well. For example `"ID1"` for first type of cells and `"ID2"` for other cells.

```
This simple example should fix the problem

NSString *identifier = nil;
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
if ((row >= 5 && row <= 10) || row == 16) {
    identifier = @"CELLID1";
}
else {
    identifier = @"CELLID2";
}


DetailsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
....
```

or much simpler solution is just to clean `accessoryType` at the beginning of the method for your case

```
DetailsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: I shared my code with you, but I used one Cell in my table

Comment: When you scroll cells are reused. You should read more about that. I will write solution in a min

Comment: Thank you so much for your care but it not work because i give cell name in storyboard